# Running resque-scheduler on a web farm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, delayed-job, resque

If I'm running a resque cron job to run every hour using resque-scheduler on a web farm of say 2 or 3 web servers... how do I get it so that the job isn't submitted once for each web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resque-scheduler has a scheduling process that must always be running. Only one instance of it should be started, on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

resque-scheduler just queues jobs into a Resque queue, and the first worker to get to the job pops the job off the queue and runs it. You don't have to worry about duplication by the nature of Resque's design.

Comment: so the process scheduling the jobs would run outside of a web context?

Comment: Yes. The scheduler is its own process that must always be running. Don't run it on multiple servers.